# Is there a function in elisp to apply a patch to a buffer?

Tags: emacs, diff, elisp, patch

I am working on an emacs mode for a review tool, and want to use ediff for viewing diffs... the problem is that the review tool only yields a diff, rather than old and new files. I'd like to put the old file in a buffer and apply a diff rather than copying the file, calling out to diff as a subprocess and loading it into a separate buffer.

Can this be done without writing it myself, does anyone know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**ediff-patch-buffer** can be used to *patch a buffer* in ediff-mode

Comment: Nice hint, however this will create a patched buffer with "_patched" appended to its name. I think you have to manually copy over the contents after that.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what your workflow is this may or may not apply.

Try

```
M-x diff-mode
```

From which you can do commands like:

```
C-c C-a         diff-apply-hunk
C-c C-b         diff-refine-hunk
C-c C-c         diff-goto-source
C-c C-d         diff-unified->context
C-c C-e         diff-ediff-patch
```

The most intuitive flow for me is the `'diff-ediff-patch`.

When you're looking at a patch, run <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd>, enter the file name to patch (say `file.to.patch`).  Emacs will then set you up with an ediff of two buffers `file.to.patch.orig` and `file.to.patch` containing the original file and the patched version.  You then use ediff as you would regularly.  At the end of the flow, you have the patched version in the filename you want.

Check out the [documentation for diff-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Diff-Mode.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is also `M-x epatch` that asks for a buffer containing a patch (Gnus mail for example) and then asks for a file/directory to patch. Very handy.

Comment: The `epatch` command is very useful to apply a patch to a file.  It will generate a reject file for any hunk that could not be applied (if for example, the hunk identifies something that is already inside the target file).